# Pass extra argument into callback

Tags: node.js, module

Say I have a function with a callback:

```
client.on("foo", (arg1, arg2, arg3) => { 
    // ...
    client.bar();   
} );
```

Now I want to seperate the callback into a different module:

```
const eventHandler = require('./eventHandler.js');

client.on("foo", eventHandler.foo);
```

I now need access to the `client`variable in the `eventHandler.js` module, because I need to call `client.bar();`. How would I go about passing `client` into the `eventHandler.foo` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an inline callback and call the event handler with any arguments you want.

Example:

```
client.on("foo", () => eventHandler.foo(client));
```

However, looking at your code, it appears that the `on` event is a property on the `client` itself. Can't you just edit the code of `client` and make it pass itself as an argument to the callback function?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!